# How to change thread pool size in ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java

I need ScheduledExecutorService with a dynamic thread pool. I want to change the thread pool size dynamically. How can I do this?

```
class ExecutorTask {
    private ScheduledExecutorService service;

    public void add(Task task) {
        // I need thread pool size == count added tasks.
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::start, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can advice me another thread pool?

Comment: This is one of the few times where utilizing the thread pool constructors directly is more beneficial than the static factory methods located in `Executors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

```
    //Init executor
    int initialPoolSize = 5;
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(initialPoolSize);

    //[...] do something

    //Change max size
    int newPoolSize = 10;
    executor.setCorePoolSize(newPoolSize);
```

Note that the inherited method [setMaximumPoolSize(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int)) has [no effect on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). To change the pool size you need to change the corePoolSize:

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the
>   inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. **In particular, because
>   it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an
>   unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect.**
>   Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to
>   zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool
>   without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I reduce thread pool? If initialPoolSize = 5 ,,, and than newPoolSize = 2.?

Comment: Yes, but only if you allow the ThreadPool to "cool down". Check this example: https://repl.it/repls/FirmVioletredSyntax - here it works, after reducing core size, the number of active threads goes down to 1. But if you decrease the `waitingPeriod` to 500ms (Line 28), the threads never time out: https://repl.it/repls/EarnestFloralwhiteSpheres . Actually, I thought you could tweak that by changing the `keepAliveTime` to a number smaller than `waitingPeriod`, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help it was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setCorePoolSize(int)` method for that.

Also using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` you provide the responsibility of creating the thread pool size to `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` creates new threads if needed to execute the new tasks, and reuses the existing ones with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that is what you are looking for in the Executors Util class:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5)
```

Comment: No, in this case, I couldn't change executorService thread pool if a number of tasks will be increased. I can set thread pool size only once and can't change it in runtime.